# How to enable dropping any file type on particular or any Unity launcher item?

Tags: unity, launcher, drag-and-drop

For example I cannot drag and drop folders and .py files to the [meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) using launcher but it accepts them perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locate the .desktop of app you wish to adjust, in the case  meld & open in a text editor.

Usually there will be a line, MimeType=, just add to it the appropriate type, if you don't know then a right click > Properties > Type will show.

So in this case, 'Meld', you'd add this to the end of the MimeType= line

```
text/x-python;inode/directory;
```

If for some reason the line didn't exist the just add it, like

```
MimeType=text/x-python;inode/directory;
```

Usually a logout/in will be needed to reflect changes.

For meld - try also editing the Exec= line in the .desktop to this

```
Exec=meld %F
```

Other possibilities for letter would be f or U, though glancing at the report I'm not sure it will matter much here with meld

Comment: Great :) Editing it right now. Can I use wildcards?

Comment: It didn't work for meld (bug report: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=641948 ). But it answers the question.

Comment: wildcards?, I don't know, never tried. I'd think better to add specific types as desired. Generally it seems .desktops no longer have a inode/directory entry, though I do edit in for a few media players. Though having it show is no guarantee that the app can deal with properly as you've seen. Never tried with meld, if any solution appears will edit in to answer

Comment: BTW, `MimeType=inode/directory;text/*;` worked as expected.